# Minutes To Years ,Days , Hours and Miniutes convereter

Tags: java, date, time, duration, days

my problem is that i am unable to get the days correctly.
help me out!

here is my code.

```java
package basic.programs;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinutesToYearDaysConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Minutes, Years, MinutesRemain, Days, MinutesRemainAfterDays, Hours, MinutesRemainAfterHours;
        
        System.out.print("give the minutes : ");
        Minutes = sc.nextInt();
        Years = Minutes / 535600;
        MinutesRemain =  Minutes % ( 535600);
        Days = MinutesRemain / 1440;
        MinutesRemainAfterDays =  MinutesRemain % (1440 );
        Hours =  MinutesRemainAfterDays / 60;
        MinutesRemainAfterHours = MinutesRemainAfterDays % (60);
        System.out.print("Given minutes has" + Years + "years" + Days +  "days" + Hours +  "hours and " + MinutesRemainAfterHours +  "minutes ");
    }
}
```

output :-

```
give the minutes : 3000010
Given minutes has 5 years 223 days14 hours and 50 minutes
```

//      Write a Java program to convert minutes into the number of years, days, hours and minute.
//      Ex : Input : minutes = 3000010 Output : Given minutes has 5 years 258 days 8 hours and 10 minutes

i tried to input the same minutes that the problem gave as an example to check if my code runs correctly or not.

so where am i missing.

Comment: Why do you put the number of minutes in parentheses after the remainder operation ``Minutes % ( 535600)``?

Comment: Do you check for leap years?

Comment: Java naming conventions have classes start with an upper case letter; variables and methods start with lower case letters (minutes, years, etc).

Comment: It seems there's a typo in the number of minutes per year: `1440 * 365 = 525_600`, however, if counting 365.25 days per year, it may be: `525_960` minutes per year

Answer (score 2):

That is a lot of magic numbers for functionality that Java includes in [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html). Unfortunately, it doesn't provide a `toYears()` (and your math assumes one year is exactly 365 days). Anyway, that could be done with something like

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("give the minutes : ");
int origMinutes = sc.nextInt();
long days = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toDays(origMinutes);
long years = days / 365;
days -= years * 365;
long hours = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toHours(origMinutes
        - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes(years * 365)
        - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes(days));
long minutes = origMinutes
        - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes(years * 365)
        - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes(days)
        - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hours);
System.out.printf("Given minutes has %d years %d days %d hours and %d minutes%n",
        years, days, hours, minutes);
```

Running with your sample input, yields your sample output.

```
give the minutes : 3000010
Given minutes has 5 years 258 days 8 hours and 10 minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

In one year there are 525600 minutes, not 535600.

```
Years = Minutes / 525600;
MinutesRemain =  Minutes % ( 525600);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you do it using [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html). I also recommend you follow **[Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)** e.g. your variables, `Minutes, Years, MinutesRemain` etc. should be named as `minutes, years, minutesRemain` etc.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter minutes: ");
        int mins = sc.nextInt();
        Duration d = Duration.ofMinutes(mins);
        long days = d.toDaysPart();
        long hours = d.toHoursPart();
        long minutes = d.toMinutesPart();
        System.out.print("Given minutes has " + days / 365 + " years " + days % 365 + " days " + hours + " hours and "
                + minutes + " minutes.");
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter minutes: 3000010
Given minutes has 5 years 258 days 8 hours and 10 minutes.
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: How’s your answer any different that mine posted 10 min before yours, other than yours has more words?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar - Let me check your answer.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar - Did you try compiling your code? There does not exist any method such as `Duration#toYears`. An idea should be posted as a comment (as many other contributors have already done), not as an answer.

Comment: You’re right. I didn’t compile, but I checked the Javadoc, and thought saw the method. I don’t have time to compile code for every homework that’s posted on this site.